# VB.net Geckofx How to get link from Anchor text

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

Please  i want to get the href value "/contact.php"

```
<a href="/contact.php">Contact</a>

For Each a In wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        If a.InnerHtml = "Contact" Then
           'getting the href value
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
Dim value As String = a.GetAttribute("href");
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it would resolve the issue?

Comment: What is there to explain. He wanted to get the href, this is how you get the href.  Edited for capital G GetAttribute.